# How to auto adjust menus height according to container height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap's latest version for my latest project. I stuck in header section. I want auto adjust height of menus according to logo height, so that logo in any dimensions can't effect on the menus height.

Even i don't know if it's possible or not with bootstrap. I know how to adjust the height with javascirpt but don't want with javascript. I am curious if there is a way to adjust height?

```
    <div id="main-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 logo">
                    <hgroup>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/141x55" />
                    </hgroup>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 main-menu">
                    <div class="menu clearfix">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-header{
    background-color: #efefef;
    height: auto;
}
#main-header .logo{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
#main-header .main-menu{
    height: auto;
}
#main-header .menu li a{
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

Here is the fiddle of what i am trying: [<kbd>JSFIDDLE</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/aGHp4/embedded/result/)

Comment: can you use javascript to fix the height?

Comment: @KawineshSK I can do it with javascript but i don't want, If it is possible with CSS then i don't think we have to use JS. That's why i asked if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `height:100%` css property. height:100% will always cover up the height of the parent element. So if you want the menu div to cover up the height, then give height:100% to the menu

```
<div class="menu clearfix" style="height:100%">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

By doing this, now menu will occupy the full height of the parent div i.e. `<div class="col-lg-8 main-menu">`
Similarly if required you can follow the approach for other elements.

Comment: @jogesh_pi Here my attempt: http://jsbin.com/mujiziqe/1/edit Just note that the `#main-header` itself MUST have an explicit `height`